# Annotate One variable in a stacked Bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a bar chart that gets the max value from a group and then aggregates the remaining lower values together and lumps them into a "other" group.

How Can I just Annotate the max value group while ignoring the other group.

This here code I found for annotation on bar charts works well usually but will annotate both charts. Anyone have any idea how I can fix it?

For example, here is a sample of my problem

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

d = {'Group': ['a'], '6 Month Projection': [100]}
dff = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
# dff['6 Month Projection'] = dff['6 Month Projection']/1000000
# dff
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x_bar = dff['Group']
y_bar = dff['6 Month Projection'][0]
z_bar = 50
# plt.bar(x_bar,y_bar)



plt.bar(x_bar, z_bar)
plt.bar(x_bar, y_bar, bottom=z_bar,color='orange')


for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate("%.2f" % p.get_height(), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()), ha='center', va='center', xytext=(0, 10), textcoords='offset points')



fig.text(0.9, 0.05, '$Group$')
fig.text(0.1, 0.95, 'Revenue in Millions')
# ax.set_ylim(bottom=10.00)
# ax.set_ylim(top=12.75)
# fig.set_size_inches(10,5)
plt.show()
# # plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)
# # plt.ylabel('Usage')
# # plt.title('Programming language usage')

# plt.show()
```

Does anyone know how I can annotate just the Blue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In matplotlib 3.4.0 or newer, you can just set [bar_label](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-bar-label) for the first container:

```
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], fmt='%.2f')
```

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

dff = pd.DataFrame({'Group': ['a', 'b'],
                    '6 Month Projection': [100, 175],
                    'Blue': [50, 75]})
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x_bar = dff['Group']
y_bar = dff['6 Month Projection']
z_bar = dff['Blue']
ax.bar(x_bar, z_bar)
ax.bar(x_bar, y_bar, bottom=z_bar, color='orange')

# Set labels for first container only
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], fmt='%.2f')
fig.text(0.9, 0.05, '$Group$')
fig.text(0.1, 0.95, 'Revenue in Millions')
plt.show()
```

[image: plot with blue bars annotated]

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to achieve what you want.
The simplest would be to loop through the created patches when only the bottom ones have been created.  Another way is to test whether the y-position of the bar is zero:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'Group': ['a'], '6 Month Projection': [100]}
dff = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x_bar = dff['Group']
y_bar = dff['6 Month Projection'][0]
z_bar = 50

ax.bar(x_bar, z_bar)
ax.bar(x_bar, y_bar, bottom=z_bar, color='orange')

for p in ax.patches:
    if p.get_y() == 0:
        ax.annotate("%.2f" % p.get_height(), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()), ha='center', va='center',
                    xytext=(0, 10), textcoords='offset points')

fig.text(0.9, 0.05, '$Group$')
fig.text(0.1, 0.95, 'Revenue in Millions')
plt.show()
```

[image: annotating the lower bars]

Some remarks:

- with `fig, ax = subplots(...)` you opt for the ["object-oriented"](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/) plotting interface; it is recommended to stay using `ax` to tell matplotlib which "subplot" to use.
- to position the text just on top of the bar, you need to sum `p.get_y()` with `p.get_height()`. (This wouldn't make a difference for the bars that have 0 as bottom.)